# Checkbox in note editor - UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, editor, uwp

I just wondering if there is a way to place Checkboxes beside a text line in a edit panel like richtextbox.
What I mean is something like Onenote app and a simple to-do list:

[image]

Is it possible to do this with build-in UWP element or ...?

Comment: Ya in UWP it's called [RichEditBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx) instead of `RichTextBox` and supports `InlineUIContainer` like you're probably used to plop in inline CLR objects. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, There is no InlineUIContainer in RichEditBox and that support in RichTextBlock. But the problem is, it's not an editor as I want. 
I just want something that when user start typing in each line, there would be a checkbox beside the text that user already typed...

Comment: Ah shoot, sorry about that then, I skip between all the xamls so much sometimes the nuances are forgotten. Are you saying that say for example, user types a line, checkbox appears next to it, then they linefeed to a new line and start typing and a checkbox appears next to that, and so on, and so on?

Comment: @ChrisW. yeah just like that. to be clear, just like the picture (from Onenote app). I search a lot about it and I couldn't find something like that.

Comment: You could just have something like an items control with CheckBox as ItemTemplate next to a TextBox and on linefeed/return of the TextBox create a new CheckBox item and match the spacing with LineHeight to provide the same functionality. The association between lines would be the tricky part I imagine, but that's pretty broad I know.

Comment: hi @Mehrdad Kamali have you got any solution for this, I am also in a same situation . I need add checkbox inside richeditbox. Please share ur solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RichTextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Paragraph>
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="ChkName" />
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="RolePageName" Text="Pages Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,-7,0,0" />
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBlock>
```

**Hope so is will work for you.
Thanks**